# Magento product custom option added in admin but does not show at front

Tags: php, magento

We added a custom option in our magento product by using the import option and updated the product catalog. It's successfully done and we also did indexing but it's still not showing this option on front.

We also tried a custom script for saving the product data manually. Still it didn't show on front.

But when we open the product and click on save then and only then it works, but we can't use this manual method because there are thousands of products. So please suggest a good solution for this issue.

Find image below for reference:
[image]

Comment: A good solution would be to contact their support. Your question seems off-topic unless you have a *programming* question related to magneto; in which case post the relevant code

Answer (score 0):

In your custom script, did you set the store to admin?

```
Mage::app()->setCurrentStore(Mage_Core_Model_App::ADMIN_STORE_ID);
```